# Is there a tool to convert T-SQL Stored Procedures to C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

**Update from 2017:**

Realistically, the answer is **no, and even if there were you should be extremely cautious of using it**.

There are really only two ways to attack this problem:

a) Bite the bullet and convert everything manually and painstakingly and with some method of verification to check that everything continues to behave as intended, like unit/regression tests. Use tools like Linqer, if available, as *assistance*, to solve a part of the problem.

b) Start over from scratch.

There is no option c) to have something else handle everything neatly and automatically, and it could not possibly cover all cases. There are many things T-SQL can do that LINQ can't (updates, inserts and deletes spring to mind), and many things that you would be better off doing a different way in C# (like cursors).

Very few problems like this get well-engineered, exhaustive solutions that can be trusted not to regress functionality (like commercial VB6 to VB.NET converters that could justify spending enormous effort because of the sheer volume of potential customers out there, and where you can pick up a phone or a lawyer if something goes wrong), so if such a tool existed you should be extremely careful. The translation from the LINQ-compatible subset of SQL to LINQ is a bounded problem that is well-understood by the  and I think Linqer can be trusted.

This question was trying to suss out a tool that could assist with option a) but I imagine many people reading this are looking for option c). There is a subset of this question and answer that is not a horrible idea, but it does not automate away the remaining burden, since even many of the simple stored procedures did more than querying in a LINQ-expressible form. It was still far too untenable to do option a) for any of the projects I mentioned.

---

Original question follows:

I have a few projects to maintain that use a lot of SQL Server stored procedures (in T-SQL). I know how to maintain them, but since there are many tools to automatically convert between different languages, I'm wondering if there's any tool to convert the stored procedures to C# code?

I do NOT want to convert them to CLR Stored Procedures; I simply want to migrate the logic in my data layer to the C# end of my project and automate the grunt work. Most of the stored procedures (maybe 70%?) are simple "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @id" affairs, and they could be done just as well with Entity Framework.

I know that it's not a straight line between T-SQL and C# as it is from VB.NET to C# and that conversion isn't as straightforward; you will need to introduce a data layer in C#, for example, and some things like cursors don't have corresponding concepts. I just want to move off of stored procedures without the repetitive manual labor if possible.

Since this has been put into question by faulty assumptions: I already know T-SQL, and given the code of any one of these stored procedures I could tell you what they do. There are very good practical reasons why I do not want the logic to continue residing in stored procedures.

Comment: Don't do this...  No.

Comment: Bad idea - T-SQL stored procedures are powerful and used for a reason - moving them to C# doesn't give you any benefits - but lots of drawbacks. Don't do it. Get used to T-SQL.

Comment: I rephrased my question. The stored procedures mostly aren't stored procedures doing what T-SQL does best, but stored procedures for the sake of being stored procedures because doing a plain, naked SELECT is bad for the soul. Please reconsider.

Comment: If you were starting over, this might be a different discussion (And I'm sure there are lots of threads on here about the use of Stored Procedures). But since they're already implemented that way, please don't change them to C#.

Comment: I think this is a valid question.  There might currently be business logic in the stored procs that'd be better moved into the application layer; or it could be as a learning exercise.

Comment: Either way, there is nothing that will convert such stored procedures to C# without considerable manual effort.  It works now, but you can't be sure it will work later, and I don't know anyone who would want to foot the expense to change so much and actually change nothing.

Comment: Chris: Exactly. I know for a fact that there's nothing that couldn't be implemented just as well by a method in a data layer class using the corresponding LINQ statements. It's not a learning exercise. I know both T-SQL and C# all too well, and I just don't want to work in T-SQL unless I'm doing something that needs to be done in it (like cursors or CTEs) because of maintainability concerns. I want to *migrate*, not keep them in sync, which is why I don't quite understand Fosco's concern.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's a good idea - and there are good arguments either way - it's a good question to ask how this might be possible, irrespective of the merit of doing so.

Comment: Maintainability?... T-SQL is a standard that's been relatively unchanged for over a decade, and C# was born and has gone through 4 major versions in that time.  It makes sense that you don't understand my concern, as I certainly don't understand yours. :)

Comment: T-SQL has been as much of a pain in the ass to work with as a programmer for as long as it's been around, correct. Just joking, mostly. I can do so much more when it's code in C# instead of T-SQL inside stored procedures.

Comment: +1 @marc_s - Get used to working with T-SQL. Don't move code around just because you're not as comfortable in the language. Sure C# can do more as it's a general purpose programming language. That doesn't make it the best tool for every task. Keep data access in the database where it belongs.

Comment: @Yuck: I am used to working with T-SQL. The data access is a complete mess. I inherited this code and I want to be able to make sense of it. It's the particular code I'm not comfortable with, not the language. I will be just as uneasy with the logic in C#, but I will at least be able to fix it more easily and use more sophisticated tools to refactor it. I'll do that the hard way, converting the stored procedures line by line if I have to, but I thought I'd see if there were ways of automating the process as far as possible.

Comment: I encourage you to come to http://dba.stackexchange.com and ask this same question, but in the vein of learning something new.

Comment: @drachenstern: Thank you, but I could already tell you what each of these stored procedures do in great detail given their T-SQL source. What I can't tell you is how I can maintain a bunch of stored procedures to the same extent that I can evolve and understand a C# code base.

Comment: @Jesper ~ That's a shame then, for two reasons. One was my point of learning something new, which you say you don't need. Two was your assertion that C# is equivalent to SQL. Cheers and hope you have a good day.

Comment: @drachenstern: C# is NOT equivalent to SQL. I said as much in the post. But as part of transforming a data layer where stored procedures and a C# program with data readers are used to a data layer where, say, Entity Framework and LINQ queries are used, you need to translate the T-SQL code in the stored procedures to the C# code that does the same thing. In terms of the 70% of the stored procedures that are just simple SELECTs with filters, it won't be recognizably code, but it is code in the shape of LINQ queries. And in the terms of the other 30% it is definitely code.

Comment: Found this since I'm considering the same move. I simply want to be able to source control my data access code together with the applications and do not want Busincess Logic in my DAL.

Comment: Those supporting putting a ton of business logic into stored procedures don't make any sense to me.  Those saying that, have they ever written well multi-layered applications with real separations of concerns?  Or do you work in siloed environments where you just write procedures without any other cares in the world!?!?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/):

> Linqer is a SQL to LINQ converter
>   tool. It helps you to learn LINQ and
>   convert your existing SQL statements.
>
> Not every SQL statement can be
>   converted to LINQ, but Linqer covers
>   many different types of SQL
>   expressions.
>
> Because LINQ is a part of C#, it is
>   sensitive to data types conversion.
>   Linqer performs required type castings
>   in the produced LINQ statements.

Comment: Neat little program.  Unfortunately, you'd have to paste every query in here, and while it provides a LINQ query it won't create the actual code you need to replace the current stored procedure call.

Comment: @Fosco: Yeah, it's not ideal. I'll have to do it one stored procedure at a time, but I can at least search across my C# project for the stored procedure.

Comment: @Jesper any chance you can post some code?  I really cannot figure out how a simple stored procedure like select * from x where id = @param is causing you so much trouble... and bringing LINQ into it rather than just turning it into a SQLCommand... mind blown.  I'm starting to think the code issues have little to do with the data access.

Comment: @Fosco I think you might've missed the point, it's not about being uncomfortable with SQL, it's more about consolidating logic by moving data access code out of the database and into the application.  LINQ also has some benefits over SQL, it gives you a strongly typed DAL over the database for compile-type safety, and is a standardised query language that's used over other data sources like XML and in-memory objects.

Comment: @Chris It's definitely going to be a very manual process, which did not strike me as a good solution for an existing and functioning app.  You make interesting points though, and I plan on spending a lot of time with LINQ on new apps in the near future.

Comment: @Fosco: As Chris said, it's not the simple SELECT stored procedures that's the problem. There being many of them is a definite problem, but there's also some stored procedures that are considerably more advanced.

Comment: I just downloaded it ran it it AV'ed out and then AVG gave me trojan downloader alert Tutils.exe in temp. I would have to investigate but avg runs all the time Dont know if they are linked but be careful.